# Errno::ENOENT in <ControllerName>#<ActionName>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-uploading, minimagick

I'm Trying to upload an image but I get this error:

[image]

[image]

So here is my Controller:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
   def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params) 
    @recipe.chef = Chef.find(1) #temporal to use Gravatar

    if @recipe.save
        flash[:success] = "Your recipe was created successfully!"
        redirect_to recipes_path
    else
        render :new
    end
  end

  private

    def recipe_params
        params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :summary, :description, :picture)
    end
end
```

My Model

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :chef
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :summary, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  validate :picture_size

  private
    def picture_size
        if picture.size > 5.megabytes
            errors.add(:picture, "should be less than 5 MB")    
        end
    end
end
```

gem 'carrierwave', '0.10.0'
gem 'mini_magick', '3.8.0'

Both Gems are in my GemFile and I have Installed ImageMagick on Windows.

ImageUploader.rb

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  process resize_to_limit: [600,600]

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

end
```

Hope you guys can help me!

Comment: It looks to me that the problem is with the ImageMagick side of things. What happens if you comment out lines 3 and 4 of PictureUploader. That is, comment out `include CarrierWave::MiniMagick` and `process resize_to_limit: [600,600]`. If the upload then works - you'll know you need to look at your ImageMagick configuration.

Comment: Thanks @ReggieB it worked !!